# How can I define a async generator function as a javascript class member function?

Tags: javascript, class, asynchronous, generator, member-functions

I have a pure ES6+ class. (node18+)

I would like to define an async generator member function, like:

`class A { async *mygenerator() {} }`

In typescript it is possible, but the transpiled code is not really useful.

So in typescript, this is valid:

`class A { public static async *myfunc<T>(): AsyncGenerator<T, void, void> {} }`

Maybe this is not possible in pure js classes...

-- UPDATE --

The syntax check fails when using the linter.

Is there any linter option to prevent this to interpret as a valid syntax?

```
    {
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:node/recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "airbnb-base"
  ],
  "plugins": ["node", "prettier"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2022,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "block-scoped-var": "error",
    "eqeqeq": "error",
    "no-var": "error",
    "no-console": "error",
    "prefer-const": "error",
    "eol-last": "error",
    "prefer-arrow-callback": "error",
    "no-trailing-spaces": "error",
    "quotes": ["warn", "single", { "avoidEscape": true }],
    "no-restricted-properties": [
      "error",
      {
        "object": "describe",
        "property": "only"
      },
      {
        "object": "it",
        "property": "only"
      }
    ],
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        "endOfLine": "auto"
      }
    ],
    "id-length": ["error", { "min": 2 }],
    "comma-dangle": 0,
    "max-params": ["error", 3],
    "node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax": ["error", { "ignores": ["modules"] }],
    "import/no-unresolved": "off",
    "node/no-missing-import": "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
    "no-useless-constructor": "off",
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "import/extensions": "off",
    "object-curly-newline": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "import/no-absolute-path": "off",
    "node/no-unpublished-import": "off",
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "lines-between-class-members": "off",
    "camelcase": "off",
    "operator-linebreak": "off",
    "implicit-arrow-linebreak": "off",
    "function-paren-newline": "off",
    "no-shadow": "off",
    "indent": "off",
    "brace-style": "off"
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? That works fine in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript async generator example:

```js
async function* foo() {
  yield await Promise.resolve('a');
  yield await Promise.resolve('b');
  yield await Promise.resolve('c');
}

let str = '';

async function generate() {
  for await (const val of foo()) {
    str = str + val;
  }
  console.log(str);
}

generate();
```

Typescript is a strongly typed language, Javascript is a weakly typed language. So you will not be able to specify the types in Javascript like you do in Typescript. But nevertheless you can create async generators in Javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncGenerator

Inside class

```
class YourClass {
    async * yourMethod(msg) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

EDIT

Of course, async generators can be class members as well

Comment: The question was about a class member function, but the question already contains the correct solution so I'm not sure it matters.

Comment: So I disabled some linter options based on the linter errors, and now it is valid. I know the js generators anyway, but this was pure javascript api to fix, and not typescript I am using recently. That's why I was not sure if this is valid. My bad.

<!-- language: lang-js -->

/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier /
/ eslint-disable no-restricted-syntax */
<!-- end snippet -->

Thanks to move me to the right path. Next time I will think it through before raising a question.

Comment: @Loopilla it is perfectly valid to ask questions, even if it turns out later that we could have found out the answer. It's always easy to be wise in hindsight and I have also asked questions on SO only to realize based on the answer that I could have figured it out. So, please don't worry about it. It's normal that we do not figure out everything.